# Як перекласти словосполучення "killer tips"?

Tags: переклад, from-english, словосполучення

Досить часто натрапляю на словосполучення "killer tips" (наприклад [тут](https://visual.ly/community/infographic/how/11-killer-tips-stop-saying-um-forever), [тут](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/10-killer-tips-to-write-an-unbeatable-resume_us_582dd4b9e4b08c963e343bb9) і ось [тут](https://www.apnaahangout.com/crack-ssb-interview/)). Якогось чіткого визначення цього словосполучення мені знайти не вдалося, однак я розумію, що це якісь дієві поради, які точно принесуть користь.

В [Кембріджському словнику](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/killer) знайшов таке визначення слова "killer" - це щось чи хтось дуже цікавий та досвідчений (див. 3 значення), ну а слово "tip" - це порада.

Однак, не розумію як найкраще перекласти це словосполучення, бо Гугл видає варіант "[поради для вбивць](https://translate.google.com/?hl=uk#en/uk/killer%20tips)", що точно не те, що потрібно. З іншими онлайн словниками така ж історія (та й навіть саме слово "killer" вони перекладають як "вбивця" чи "кіллер").

То як, все-таки, найкраще перекласти це словосполучення?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Це словосполучення пов'язано з таким значенням дієслова "kill," як в одному іншому словосполученні, ["kill it"](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Kill%20It):

> **Finishing** something in an **epic way**.
>
> to express **success** after having a good night.

Тип/тіп - це [порада](https://www.yenotes.com/uk/?q=TIP&from_lang=en&to_lang=uk). Беручи до уваги значення словосполучень вище, "killer tip," - це порада, яка точно призведе до успіху.

Тут, наприклад, підійде український прикметник "вбивчий":

> 2. перен. **Який дуже вражає**; **нищівний**, **разючий**.
> 3. перен. Незвичайний, надмірний у своєму прояві.
>
> //  **Дуже сильний**, важкий або неприємний.

Я б використав словосполучення "**вбивчі поради**". Майже прямий [переклад](https://www.yenotes.com/uk/?q=killer&from_lang=en&to_lang=uk).

Так само можна використати прикметники *епічний, крутезний, чудовий*. Тоді **"епічні поради", "крутезні поради", "круті поради", "нищівні поради", "чудові поради".**

Залежно від того, як заекспресивно ви хочете висловитись, просто обирайте один з відповідників.

Comment: Гадаю, що "крутезні поради" - найкращий варіант. Чому не "вбивчі"? Я тут опитав декількох знайомих і у всі вони відповіли , що "вбивчі поради" - це якісь погані поради, які приведуть до небажаних наслідків.

Comment: @Анатолій якщо ви хочете зануритися у перекладацьку діяльність, то справді треба балансувати поміж словниковими значеннями слів і тим, як люди сприймають те чи інше слово. Втім, я б не покладався **лише** на думку людей. Ви цілком можете надати слову того значення, яке хочете утвердити, якщо впевнені у перекладі саме у такий спосіб. Все залежить від ваших потреб і контексту.